# How do I defined about the parameter in QUERY with default value which is in other model class?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Here is my variable in Subject model class.

```
public static final int ENGLISH= 1;
public static final int MATHS= 2;
public static final int CHEMISTRY = 3;
public static final int ART = 4;
public static final int MUSIC = 5;
```

Here is my QUERY.

```
SELECT s.name, s.school, s.grade, sub.[name] as sub_name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN subject sub ON s.id = sub.student_id
WHERE sub.[name] = Subject.ENGLISH;
```

When I click search button, I want to get all Subject value -> (ENGLISH,MATHS,CHEMISTRY,ART,MUSIC) for each student.
But Now I Only get ENGLISH value from Subject for each student.
How do I have to modified? Please sharing your thoughts for me! Thanks !

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (*not* an image) and expected results will help us help you. Though, considering the clause `sub.[name] = Subject.ENGLISH` I'm not surprised you're only getting English data back; seems like your data is denormalised.

Comment: So How can I change that one ? I just want to pull out all subject name when I press Search button without filling any data.

Comment: If you don't want to only select certain subjects why did you add the `WHERE sub.[name] = Subject.ENGLISH` clause in the first place?

Comment: Do you understand what the individual parts of the query are doing? If yes, then please explain so we can see whether there are misconceptions. If not, you might want to grab a SQL tutorial first.

Comment: OK Let's say If I change ENGLISH to ART, the value of ART data are coming out. But when I remove that where clause, it is still ENGLISH values are coming out !